# How to show posts from friends list only. (correctly)

Tags: php, mysql

My friends array returns as only one number instead of all the numbers.

```
($myfriends = 3)
```

should be...

```
($myfriends = 3 5 7 8 9 12).
```

If I get it to while loop... the whole thing works, but instead of showing posts in order of date like I want. 
Example:

```
(post_id 3 oct30 "post goes here")
(post_id 5 oct29 "post goes here")
(post_id 7 oct28 "post goes here")
```

Instead it shows all posts from 1 persons id ordered by date. Then after all the posts from that person. It will finally show the next person and ALL of their posts.:

```
(post_id 3 oct30 "post goes here")
(post_id 3 oct29 "post goes here")
(post_id 3 oct28 "post goes here")

(post_id 5 oct30 "post goes here")
(post_id 5 oct29 "post goes here")
(post_id 5 oct28 "post goes here")
```

and so on... any new post groups with the users older posts instead of going to the top of the feed.

I hope this makes sense... sorry for bad explanation and sloppy code

---

TABLES feed & friends below
both have auto increment primary 'id' as 1st field...and then

```
FEED TABLE
feed (post_id, posted_by, content, date_posted, date_str, pic) VALUES ('$post_id', '$posted_by', '$content', now(), '$date', '$profile_pic')

FRIENDS TABLE
friends (user_id, friend_id) VALUES ('$myId', '$friendId')
```

---

```
<div class="post container">
<?php
$addsql="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = '$session_id' ORDER by id DESC";
$addquery=mysqli_query($conn, $addsql);

while ($rowa = mysqli_fetch_array($addquery)) {
$myFriends = $rowa['friend_id'];      
?>

<?php
$feedsql = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE post_id = '$myFriends' ORDER by date_posted DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $feedsql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
$content = $row['content'];
$time = $row['date_posted'];
$date = $row['date_str'];
$pic = $row['pic'];
$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$upperUser = ucfirst($username);
?>

<?php 
$imgsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$posted_by' ";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $imgsql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
$image = $rows['image'];
$mem_id = $rows['id'];
if ($posted_by == $upperUser) {
echo " <a href='profile.php?id=$mem_id'><img  src='users/$upperUser/".$image."' alt='MEMBER Pic' /></a>"; 
} else if($posted_by !== $upperUser) {
echo " <a href='profile.php?id=$mem_id'><img  src='users/$posted_by/".$image."' alt='Profile Pic' /></a>"; 
}
} 
?> 

 <div class="each_post">
<h4><a href='profile.php?id=<?php echo $mem_id; ?>'><?php echo ucfirst($posted_by);?></a>  <small class="post_date"><?php echo $date;?></small></h4>
<p class=""><?php echo $content;?></p>
</div>
<?php
}}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should learn how to use joins

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself is caused by overwriting $myFriends variable in the while loop:

```
while ($rowa = mysqli_fetch_array($addquery)) {
    $myFriends = $rowa['friend_id'];      
?>
```

You could define $myFriends as an array and add the friend_ids to the array, however you should not this, because it is inefficient.

You can join multiple tables using the JOIN keyword in SQL. In this particular case, you will need an INNER JOIN (there are several types of joins, but it is your task to learn about them).

```
$feedsql = "SELECT * FROM feed INNER JOIN friends ON feed.posted_by=friends.friend_id WHERE friends.user_id = '$session_id' ORDER by date_posted DESC";
```

Since you did not disclose your table structures, I assumed that posted_by field in the feed table would determine who sent the post, so I can join this field on the friend_id field. If this is not the case, then you need to determine on which fields these 2 tables can be joined on.

You can even join the users table on the above 2 tables to get the details of the friends.

Comment: The JOIN is EXACTLY what I needed! Thanx Shadow! I spent a lot of time figuring that out. Not huge on php/sql, im more front end. I went to w3schools and learned about the JOIN feature. Your $feedsql was accurate but I had to change the 1st feed.posted_by to feed.post_id. (because I didnt include my tables in my 1st post...) Then it worked like magic! KUDOS x1000 points!